# Netbeans codehints for generated code

Tags: java, netbeans, auto-generate, netbeans-8, optimizer-hints

Recently my NetBeans show me a ton of yellow hints for code, that is auto-generate by NetBeans itself when creating GUI for me. Is there a way, how to get rid of it, because I obviously cannot just simple change auto-generated code.

I assume there are some new code optimizations supported in new versions of Java. And the NetBeans code inspector is able to detect them, while its GUI Builder is a bit out of date to keep up with those. I have **NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 (Build 201411181905)** and everything seems to be up-to-date.

Can I do something about it? Or do I have to live with those hints so far? Or disable them to stop bothering me...

Comment: You're probably going to have to live with it until the GUI designer catches up with it. Disabling the hint is always an option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently running Netbeans 7.2.1, and there are a bunch of options related to code completion in Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion. I hope something similar is available in the latest Netbeans!